# Can I use multiple languages using fontenc?

Tags: font-encodings

I'm a Serbian native speaker, and for my needs I found that `\usepackage[OT2]{fontenc}` works best. But I can't figure out how to switch between `[OT2]` and `[T1]`. For example I use `OT2` so most of my work is in Serbian, but if I want to write text in English I can't.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1,OT2]{fontenc}` then in principle `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont` will switch encodings but most language packages should hide that in higher level llanguage switch commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice way to do this is to create commands such as `\cyr` or `\lat` so you can easily switch from one script and language to another:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1,OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,serbian]{babel}

\newcommand{\cyr}{\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont\selectlanguage{serbian}}
\newcommand{\lat}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}
Tekst pisan c1irilicom \lat english text \cyr i opet c1irilicom.
\end{document}
```

However, `OT2` encoding is generally bad solution for the Serbian language. I'll recommend you to check the [cmsrb](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmsrb) package; it use modified version of the `OT2` encoding which is better for Serbian. Also there are alternative encodings `ECMSRB1` and `ECMSRB2`: with them you can very easy write Serbian text using only ASCII characters. With this package you will also get the correct shapes of Serbian italic letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can simply use Unicode for both Latin and Cyrillic script.  You can also load `babel` or `polyglossia` to use hyphenation patterns for Serbian.

If you are required to use PDFLaTeX, the way to accomplish this with legacy fonts is to load babel.  The hyphenation patterns for `serbian-cyrillic` support the T2A encoding.  OT2 is a seven-bit font encoding from thirty-five years ago.

This template might work for you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Solely to format the MWE for TeX.SX
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}

\babelprovide[import,main]{serbian-cyrillic}

\newcommand\textenglish[1]%
{\foreignlanguage{english}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont#1}}
\newenvironment{english}%
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}%
{\end{otherlanguage}}

\begin{document}
\textenglish{From the UN Declaration of Human Rights:}

Пошто је признавање урођеног достојанства и једнаких и неотуђивих права свих чланова људске породице темељ слободе, правде и мира у свету;

пошто је непоштовање и презирање права човека водило варварским поступцима, који су вређали савест човечанства, и пошто је стварање света у којем ће људска бића уживати слободу говора и веровања и бити слободна од страха и немаштине проглашено као највиша тежња сваког човека;
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertine font sample]

And in LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Solely to format the MWE for TeX.SX
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\babelprovide[import,main]{serbian-cyrillic}

\newcommand\textenglish[1]%
{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
\newenvironment{english}%
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}%
{\end{otherlanguage}}

\begin{document}
\textenglish{From the UN Declaration of Human Rights:}

Пошто је признавање урођеног достојанства и једнаких и неотуђивих права свих чланова људске породице темељ слободе, правде и мира у свету;

пошто је непоштовање и презирање права човека водило варварским поступцима, који су вређали савест човечанства, и пошто је стварање света у којем ће људска бића уживати слободу говора и веровања и бити слободна од страха и немаштине проглашено као највиша тежња сваког човека;
\end{document}
```

[image: Linux Libertine font sample]